# Is there a thread safe queue class for Visual Studio C++ 6.0?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, mfc

I would like to implement a thread safe queue in VS 6.0
Is there a good class to use for this? This is an MFC application using the CWinApp.

My [former](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088607/how-do-i-concurrently-download-and-convert-a-binary-file-using-threads) post lead me to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728068.aspx) but I don't have the luxury to code in VS 2010, stuck in 6.0 land.
o well.....

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you accepted the wrong answer to that question! :-) The [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375132/releasesemaphore-does-not-release-the-semaphore/2375370#2375370) I linked in my answer will work fine with VC++ 6.

Comment: Ahh man! Sorry about that, well it could be the right answer for someone else...haha o well.  I will look into your code with more detail. thank You.

Comment: @Tommy: No biggie. You're obviously fairly new, so you haven't yet realized that anytime I give an answer, accepting it should be automatic! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A thread safe queue shouldn't be particularly difficult to implement yourself. Just use a `std::deque` inside a wrapper class and then provide the access you want i.e. `push()`, `pop()`, `front()` etc. For C++ concurrency you should definitely go for [boost::thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/thread.html) use mutexes to appropriately protect the parts of the queue that need it. I think this is a worthwhile endeavour and you will learn a lot about concurrency at the same time.