# how access to size of a container vector shared by four threads

Tags: c++

How do I get four threads to access to a data container (`std::vector<unsigned int>`) and add data to it by using `my_vector.push_back()` and suspend (or sleep) the thread when the size of `my_vector` reaches a certain size.

The access to the share resource is controlled by means of a mutex. This is all fine, but I can't get the size of the shared resource (the `my_vector`). I an using C++.

excuse my english, i'm not american native

Edit @doron - I think I fixes up the grammar for you

Comment: English didn't come from America.  You probably want to use a condition variable to signal waiting threads that the container size reaches your threshold.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the std::vector in your own container class. Just a simple class to handle the mutex internally so the rest of your program doesn't need to worry about it.

That wrapper can provide a size() method that returns a cached value. When a insert/delete method is called on your wrapper, save a copy of the current size in an integer that is only modifiable from those methods, and return that from your size() method. Increment or decrement when appropriate while still inside the critical section.

How important is this size? Does it absolutely need to be accurate, particularly considering that the other threads can't do anything with the elements in the container until the thread doing an insert/remove is finished.

EDIT: From what you're describing, you seem to need a thread-safe queue. There are various ways of implementing these, but many programming APIs will provide you with packaged versions. I'm not sure of which windows API you're using, but check for some variant on "Queue" in your "Threading" section. In general, your internal size tracking variable becomes your semaphore.

You have two very different scenarios available here, depending on how you want to do this.  If threads A, B and C are filling this vector buffer, and D is emptying the elements out one at a time, the implementation is relatively simple. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375132/releasesemaphore-does-not-release-the-semaphore/2375370#2375370) is one example I came up with by looking for 'thread safe queue windows' here on SO.

If you need to 'bunch up' the bundles of data, so that D only runs when A, B and C have accumulated some amount of data, you probably want a 2 stage solution internally. Your .add_data() method, that locks internally for safety between A, B and C, will check the size of the vector and if it's over a threshold, drop it into a seperate thread-safe queue that is the input for D, then clear itself and return.

Comment: No, you can't cache the size. Accessing to a shared value must be protected by a mutex. And the mutex isn't *only* around the access to `size`; it must be locked as long as you want the value of `size` to remain valid.

Comment: The size is important, when the size is reached, other thread process tha data of the container and reset it, and it must wake up the other thread to get more data and fill again the container.

Comment: I'm using the code theads of the book "WIN32 Multithreaded Programming" by Aaron Michael and Mike Woodring, if it help