# Throttling C++ threads

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to translate some C# code which creates N threads at a time and runs a function in each thread.

I have two problems:

-How do I limit N threads at a time?

-My linker doesnt appear to be recognising the static ints FastestMemory and SlowestMemory when I refer to them in my main method (when I print the values out at the end).

Could somebody please help?

So far I have:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


class Test{

public: 
    static unsigned int FastestMemory;
    static unsigned int SlowestMemory;

    public: 
        Test(unsigned a, unsigned b){
            FastestMemory = a;
            SlowestMemory = b;
        }


    struct thread_data
    {
        int m_id;
        thread_data(int id) : m_id(id) {}
    };

    static DWORD WINAPI thread_func(LPVOID lpParameter)
    {
        thread_data *td = (thread_data*)lpParameter;

        int RepetitionNumber = td->m_id;

        printf("thread with id = " + RepetitionNumber + '\n');

        unsigned int start = clock();

        vector<byte> list1;
        vector<byte> list2;
        vector<byte> list3;

        for(int i=0; i<10000000; i++){
            list1.push_back(57);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i=i+2)
        {
            list2.push_back(56);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            byte temp = list1[i];
            byte temp2 = list2[i];
            list3.push_back(temp);
            list2[i] = temp;
            list1[i] = temp2;
        }

        unsigned int timetaken = clock()-start;
        printf(RepetitionNumber + "  Time taken in millisecs: " + timetaken);

        if(timetaken < FastestMemory){
            FastestMemory = timetaken;
        }
        if(timetaken > SlowestMemory){
            SlowestMemory = timetaken;
        }

        return 0;
    }
};


    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {

        Test* t = new Test(2000000,0);

        for (int i=0; i< 10; i++)
        {
            CreateThread(NULL, 0, Test::thread_func, new Test::thread_data(i) , 0, 0);
        }

        printf("Fastest iteration:" + Test::FastestMemory + '\n'); //Linker not recognising
        printf("Slowest iteration:" + Test::SlowestMemory + '\n'); //Linker not recognising

        int a;

        cin >> a;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean about "limit N threads at a time". Do you mean you want (for example) to only use, say, 5 threads to execute the 10 tasks in your question?

If so, you might want to use a thread pool of some sort. Windows has something like three separate thread pool APIs, along with I/O completion ports, which can also act as thread pools. It's also pretty easy to write a thread pool of your own if you find them lacking -- but the structure is quite a bit different from what you've posted.

The `static unsigned int FastestMemory;` *declares* but does not *define* the variable. You need to define it outside of the class definition:

```
class Test {
    static unsigned int FastestMemory;
    static unsigned int SlowestMemory;
    // ...
};

unsigned int Test::FastestMemory = 0;
unsigned int Test::SlowestMemory = 0;
```

Comment: Hi Jerry, yes I do mean 5 threads to execute 10 tasks (therefore roughly two iterations of threads executing).

Comment: @user1107474: In that case you want a thread pool. The basic idea would be to create a [thread-safe queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375132/releasesemaphore-does-not-release-the-semaphore/2375370#2375370). Put your `thread_data` into the queue in main. Your thread function repeatedly retrieves an item from the queue, processes it, then retrieves another (that question has some sample code showing the general idea).

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring but not defining your static ints.

Try:

```
class Test{

public: 
    static unsigned int FastestMemory;
    static unsigned int SlowestMemory;
    // ...
};

unsigned int Test::FastestMemory = 0;
unsigned int Test::SlowestMemory = 0;
```

As for defining N threads, looking at what you have so far, try using [`CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create individual threads and scale up as needed. Of course just doing this will give you a very basic and probably not very useful threading model. I suggest reading up on thread pools.

Comment: He's really declaring but not defining.

Comment: @Konrad, I am using CreateThread- but I am not sure how I delay the next group of threads to run, until the first has finished?

Comment: Good spot, it has been a long day ;-)