# C++ MFC Keeping Track of Event Calls

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, mfc

I have a main thread and another worker thread that performs some processing. I am currently signalling events from the main thread that the worker thread should respond to. In my main thread, I have the following:

```
frameNo = 1;
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    frameNo++;
    tEvent->SetEvent();
}
```

In my worker thread, I have this:

```
int RThread::Run()
{   
    while (1) {
        WaitForSingleObject(myEvent->m_hObject, INFINITE);
        std::cout << "Event signalled!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Frame number is: " + std::string(obj->frameNo) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As of right now, the worker thread only prints that frameNo is equal to 11, I'm assuming because the main thread is iterating so quickly that the worker thread only reaches that stage when frameNo is already incremented to 11. As a result, it's missing the numbers 1-10.

I don't want to miss the numbers 1-10 though, even though it may be a bit behind.

How can I somehow keep track of how many times the event is set? I was thinking of just not using events at all and, instead, just using a Queue to push variables to while the worker thread just takes from the queue. But if I use that queue, would I need some sort of critical section around the queue since both threads are modifying it?

Comment: You need something like a queue. Take perhaps a look a my article https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/283034/Work-queue-with-std-or-Boost-threads

Comment: A quite different implementation would be to use APCs. Check the `QueueUserAPC()` function documentation. It implements a queue mechanism actually. In your thread routine you typically run a loop: `while(TRUE) { SleepEx(INFINITE,TRUE); }`. The thread will be sleeping unless there is an APC request in the queue. Used it in numerous cases and works really well. No further needs for synchronization. Pass `frameNo` as the APC procedure parameter.

Comment: But still, the comments of other members about poor use of multithreading are something to consider. If all you want is the processing of the frames to be done in another thread, and this thread will be processing ALL frames sequentially, why have the scheduling of the frame-processing requests done in the UI thread, with the worker thread processing each frame? Why not simply put all these in the worker thread instead?

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I think I see what you mean,but I'm using the Windows MFC framework and I'm getting the messages from a message map. I don't have access to the code that actually sends the messages. You're saying that, if I had access to the code that sends the message, I could just execute the message in a different thread right?

Comment: I didn't say anything about Windows messages. I think you are somewhat confused with messages, events and the APCs I mentioned above. APC is a mechanism to post processing requests to a thread. How can you "execute a message" in another thead? Windows messages are sent to and processed by the window-owning thread, which is the main (UI) thread. What i say in my 2nd comment is why not put all that frame-processing code in the child thread (`RThread::Run()`) entrirely? No need for any kind of synchonization then (except maybe for updating UI items).

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou Ah I see now. Yes, that makes sense. I was testing something out with the code above, but what you're saying is a good point. Thanks!

Comment: @gast128: condition variables and mutexes can be replaced by the the C++ **std::packaged_task**. I have used it to handle rapidly arriving messages ( socket **accept**s) that are put into a **std::queue** to be processed sequentially. The best introduction to this idiom is Bo Qian's concise YouTube lecture called "C++ Threading #9: packaged_task".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that the child thread sees each frame individually, you'll have to add synchronization to assure strict alteration between the parent and child threads.

For example, you could do something like:

## Parent

1. generate frame
2. Signal child frame is ready
3. wait for signal from child that frame has been processed
4. repeat

## Child

1. Wait for signal from parent
2. Process frame
3. Signal parent that frame has been processed
4. repeat

However, unless you're dead set on using threads, this seems to be a poor use of threads. The main point of threads is to run things concurrently, but in this case you seem to want serial execution, so you might as well use a single thread.

Yes, you could also just queue data up for the child thread to process. Yes, that typically involves a mutex. But if you're doing multi-threaded programming, a thread-safe queue is a good thing to have around anyway. For one example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2375370/179910

Comment: thank you so much for your comment! Just a few thoughts - I'm using Windows MFC, so I just want to make sure that my main GUI thread is still able to handle any user interface events. Do you still think it's a poor use of threads? In the past, if I used a single thread, the GUI thread would be too busy to handle any other user interactions. Lastly, if I use the queue I wouldn't need to use any events right? It would just be the queue that the child thread reads from.

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::promise](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) and [std::future](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) to synchronize your thread ping pong actions. Just because you are using 28 year old MFC, doesn't mean you can't use modern C++ idioms. This capability has been around since C++11 and takes the sweat out of thread synchronization. C++11 shared smart pointers like [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) gave us leak-less dynamic memory management, and so on. Remember, C++ turns 40 soon and there are no signs yet its evolution is waning, fx, C++20 will bring us [Concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/concepts), Coroutines and [Modules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/modulus). This year Herb Sutter, chairman of the ISO C++, reported that over 200 academic wonks submitted papers last year, up from 125 the year before. And MFC can be the beneficiary if you are willing to learn something new (or your manager will let you).